# Modifying local javascript variables in the console

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

If a page has code that wraps all variables in a scope, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var attempts = 3;
});
```

Is it possible to edit the variables inside that scope from the browser console (eg Developer Tools for Chrome or Firebug for Firefox)?

Comment: No, You can change the html output and see the result. But you already know that it doesn't change the source. You can try it in debug mood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set a breakpoint. Upon reaching the breakpoint you can modify all variables that are in scope at the breakpoint - including those hidden within closures.